# MySql correlated subquery count across tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that are related with the fields below:

```
forums          topics          posts
    f_id ---- f_id  t_id ---- t_id  p_id
```

For a given `f_id` I'm trying to 2 different counts in 1 query:

1. the total numbers of `t_id` (topics)
2. the total numbers of `p_id` (posts)

for example `f_id=78` should simply result to

```
tc  |  pc
---------
4   |  3
```

Meaning there are 4 topics and a total of 3 post to those topics, all in that forum. But when I use this simple query (which is after hours of trying and research my best attempt):

```
SELECT (
SELECT COUNT( t_id ) 
FROM topics
WHERE f_id =  '78'
) AS tc, (

SELECT COUNT( p_id ) 
FROM posts
WHERE posts.t_id = topics.t_id
) AS pc
FROM topics
WHERE topics.f_id =  '78'
```

But this only results to a count for each row in topics that matches the `f_id` like this:

```
tc  |  pc
---------
4   |  0
4   |  1
4   |  2
4   |  0
```

and not a total count. I'm genuinely stuck here, even though I was pretty sure this was not a hard thing to achieve. Thanks!

---

### Edit: as requested a bit of sample data:

**forums**

```
f_id  t_name      ...
---------------------
78    Test        ...
33    Something   ...
```

**topics**

```
f_id  t_id   t_date      ...
----------------------------
78    28     2011-07-14  ...
78    53     2011-07-14  ...
78    54     2011-07-14  ...
78    56     2011-07-14  ...
33    57     2011-07-14  ...
```

**posts**

```
t_id  p_id  p_date      ...
---------------------------
54    2     2011-07-14  ...
54    4     2011-07-14  ...
53    5     2011-07-14  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the following solution that actually mixes both @Bohemian 's query with my original one and seems to work well. I'm not sure if this is the optimal way to achieve though.

```
SELECT f.f_id, (SELECT COUNT(t.t_id) 
                FROM topics t
                WHERE t.f_id =  f.f_id) AS tc, 

                COUNT(distinct p.p_id) AS pc

FROM forums f
JOIN topics t ON t.f_id = f.f_id
JOIN posts p ON p.t_id = t.t_id

WHERE f.f_id = 78
GROUP BY f.f_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `count(distinct column)` to count the number of `different` values for a column:

```
select
    f.f_id,
    count(distinct t.t_id) as tc,
    count(distinct p.p_id) as pc
from forums f
join topics t on t.f_id = f.f_id
join posts p on p.t_id = t.t_id
group by f.f_id;  -- edited. initial answer had this group by omitted
```

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but that gave me the following mysql error: `#1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause`

Comment: That oddly enough outputs `tc: 2` and `pc: 3`, even though there really are 4 distinct t_id's where f_id = 78

Comment: what's your data - could you post it in the question plz?

Comment: As requested, I added the sample data to the question :)

Comment: I think the wrong `tc` count is because the `distinct t.t_id` is counted `from forums` and that should be from the topics like the first part from my original query. Is it btw possible as well to add a `WHERE f_id=78` to it? I only seem to get errors at whatever position I try to write it in. Thanks!

Comment: I have found a solution that mixes your query with my original one that seems to work fine (even though it might not be optimal). I'll update the question for now, I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question this soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to store precalculated values of posts and threads directly in topics and forums tables accordingly, since counting (probably with distinction) is not a cheap operation.

After creating you can maintain that counters with triggers or your code.

Comment: That would indeed make up for a lot less query load and seems trivial to implement (the operation I'm describing needs to be repeated for several `f_id`). I may have overestimated the difficulty of maintaining correct count numbers in those fields.